# Use signals or Q_PROPERTY to update QML objects

Tags: qt, qml, qt-signals, qproperty

I'm very frequently receiving data from a server. This data is mainly composed of numbers. Each of them is corresponding to a QML object that would need to be updated.

What would be the best course of action between `Q_PROPERTY` and `signals` in order to update the `QML` objects from the `C++` files?

Comment: update QML objects from C++ files?

Comment: Yes. See [Qt Binding documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite nice way is to use binding to C++ object from QML.

F.ex. You have data class that should be shown to user as some qml object.

You have C++ class with data and appropriate properties:

```
class MyData
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal number READ number NOTIFY numberChanged)
    ....
    //here you implement setter function that emits numberChanged() signal

};
```

You expose your data to qml via some helper classes or directly:

```
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myData", myDataObject);
```

Than you use binding to object in your qml:

```
Text 
{
    text: myData.number 
}
```

And now you can change the data in object of MyData class and your qml updates automatically.